# What is Xijinping’s long game with regards to suppression of tech sector and foreign businesses

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, china

It’s not clear to me if Xijinping is simply jingoistic and incompetent or if there is a long game at work with respect to his economic policy. Making [consistent headlines](https://cn.wsj.com/articles/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E5%8A%A0%E5%A4%A7%E5%B0%8D%E5%A4%96%E4%BC%81%E6%96%BD%E5%A3%93-%E7%AA%81%E8%A8%AA-%E8%AA%BF%E6%9F%A5-%E6%8B%98%E7%95%99%E5%A4%9A%E7%AE%A1%E9%BD%8A%E4%B8%8B-7a3a0523) is his increasingly hostile attitude toward foreign business. Sizing this up:

- Rapidly aging population
- Failed belt and road initiative due to aggressive loans to generally not stable countries has lead to said countries frequently defaulting
- Collapsed real estate market
- Crackdown on tech sector with accompanying crash in white collar jobs
- High youth unemployment leading not only to the immediate problems that causes but also youth not building the requisite job experience to advance
- Questionable national infrastructure projects (ex: highly unprofitable high speed rail)
- Increased military spending
- Economic isolation by other countries (ex: chip act)
- Devastating consequences of zero COVID policies
- Declining foreign investment
- Massively increase government control of production with all of the detrimental effects that come from government planning
- Disappearing CEOs/business leadership that are politically threatening

Is there an economic angle available here that makes these decisions sensible in a long term, strategic, sense? Specifically with regard to the general theme of:

- Increased government control despite detrimental consequences
- Deliberate suppression of innovation
- Antagonistic stance towards his own country’s wealthiest investors